# How to restructure a sequence of dictionaries in python 2.7?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I have read and build a CSV file into a dictionary format through this process below:

```
with open("data.csv") as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```

What I am trying to do is build a for loop that parses through this dictionary series and writes to (.stdout) a new line delimited(\n) JSON series by series representation and looks like this:

```
  {
    "State":"CA",
    "points":[
      ["2015-01-01", 33.5],
      ["2016-01-01", 100.8],
      ["2018-01-01", 10.1]
    ],
    "fields":{
      "Product":"TA",
      "Line":"V1"
    }
  }
```

This is an example of the csv file:

```
STATE  DATE    VALUE PRODUCT LINE TRAN
CA    2015-01  33.5   TA      V1   4
CA    2015-05  31.7   TA      V1   4
CA    2016-01  100.8  TA      V1   4
FL    2017-01  93.5   LC      M2   2
FL    2017-03  150.5  LC      M2   4
NY    2013-01  50.4   AB      AB   1
NY    2016-01  70.5   AB      AB   1
```

And this is an example of the dictionary sequence obtained after using (DictReader):

```
{'STATE': 'CA', 'DATE': '2015-01', 'VALUE': '33.5', 'PRODUCT': 'TA', 'LINE': 'V1', 'TRAN': '4'}
{'STATE': 'CA', 'DATE': '2015-05', 'VALUE': '31.7', 'PRODUCT': 'TA', 'LINE': 'V1', 'TRAN': '4'}
```

I am stuck in the for loop middle part, I can't find out to restructure to this new jason sequence:

```
with open("data.csv") as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

for row in reader:
        for key in row:


new_jsonsqc = json.dumps(row)
sys.stdout.write(new_jsonsqc + '\n')
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: what is your desired json sequence ?

Comment: I wanted to have a series by series sequence like the one above with the unique id 'State', 'points' and 'fields' keys inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the keys and append to your new_jsonsqc accordingly:

```
import csv
import json
import sys

with open("data.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        new_jsonsqc = {'points': [], 'fields': {}}
        for key in row:
            if key == 'STATE':
                new_jsonsqc['State'] = row[key]
            if key == 'DATE':
                new_jsonsqc['points'].append(row[key])
            if key == 'VALUE':
                new_jsonsqc['points'].append(row[key])
            if key == 'PRODUCT':
                new_jsonsqc['fields']['Product'] = row[key]
            if key == 'LINE':
                new_jsonsqc['fields']['Line'] = row[key]
        sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(new_jsonsqc) + '\n')
```